# JSON and AJAX response

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, web

Hi the response i have an JSON :

```
[{"id":"1","message":"sdvsvdsdv","nickname":""},{"id":"2","message":"1234556","nickname":""},{"id":"3","message":"4555555","nickname":""}]
```

**The javascript function :**

```
function ajax_request(){

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost/chat/controller.php?showmessage";
request.open("post", url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

request.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){

               var return_data = request.responseText; // THE WHOLE JSON

               document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
}
request.send();}
```

How can i get the element "message" only not the whole JSON ?.

Comment: [Parse the JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript) into a JavaScript array, iterate over it and extract the desired data. Read [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) if you don't know how to access properties of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse("<JSON-STRING>")` to get the object out. From the object, you could extract your message.

Something like:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
for (var i=0; i<jsonObj.length; i++){
     alert(jsonObj[i].message); //alerts each "message" ..
}
```

This is something apart from the actual question, but I would really suggest you to use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) library. That takes away half of your efforts. There's a simple `$.ajax(..)` to do AJAX requests, and `$.parseJSON(..)` to parse JSON strings -- all in a cross-browser way.

Answer (score 1):

```
var returnObject = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
for (var i in returnObject) {
    document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML += '<br/>' + returnObject[i].message;
}
```

Comment: How can i make it to show the object one time not to copy it every time when im  using : setInterval(function,1000);

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
resp = '[{"id":"1","message":"sdvsvdsdv","nickname":""},{"id":"2","message":"1234556","nickname":""},{"id":"3","message":"4555555","nickname":""}]'
console.log(JSON.parse(resp)[0]['message'])
```

Use `JSON.parse()` method to convert JSON string to the JS-object

Comment: @OmarS.Ali If this helped you solve the answer, you should accept it as the answer.